# Xamarin style does not applied to custom view

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create a customized `Frame` and `View`. I combined `Frame` and `View` in `Page` with `Style` resources like below.

#### MainPage

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="local:MyFrame">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LimeGreen" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<local:MyView>
    <local:MyView.Views>
        <local:MyFrame Style="{StaticResource Style}"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Title="Number one" />
    </local:MyView.Views>
</local:MyView>
```

#### MyView

```cs
public class MyView : ContentView
{
    private readonly StackLayout _layout;
    public ObservableCollection<View> Views { get; set; }

    public MyView()
    {
        Views = new ObservableCollection<View>();
        Views.CollectionChanged += OnViewsCollectionChanged;

        _layout = new StackLayout();
        Content = _layout;
    }

    private void OnViewsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (View view in e.OldItems)
                _layout.Children.Remove(view);

        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (View view in e.NewItems)
                _layout.Children.Add(view);
    }
}
```

#### MyFrame

```cs
public class MyFrame : Frame
{
    private readonly Label _title;
    public string Title { set => _title.Text = value; }

    public MyFrame()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;

        _title = new Label
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 16,
        };

         Content = _title;
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

I expected **LimeGreen** color on `MyFrame` background because I set `MyFrame.Style` in `MainPage`, However actual result is **LightPink**.

I am guessing setting `BackgroundColor` in `MyFrame` constructor is not mean to set default. Then how can I set default `BackgroundColor` for `MyFrame`?

I simplified actual project into small reproducible project. Here is [Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/StyleDoesNotApply)

---

#### Update

Comment out `BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;` code, result in **LimeGreen** color... Then how can I set default `MyFrame.BackgroundColor`?

Comment: What do you mean by default? The `Style` is applying the default `BackgroundColor` and then you have overridden it by setting it explicitly on your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue, and i can propose the following modification of your code to be able to set the default BackgroundColor for your MyFrame view:

### Modifications on MyFrame

To solve your problem i modified MyFrame to be defined in Xaml instead:

**MyFrameXaml.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="StyleDoesNotApply.MyFrameXAML"
       BackgroundColor="{Binding MyBackgroundColor}">
    <Label x:Name="title"
           TextColor="Black"
           FontSize="16"/>
</Frame>
```

Then, in the code behind define the MyBackgroundColor property as follows:

**MyFrameXaml.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace StyleDoesNotApply
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyFrameXAML : Frame
    {

        public string Title { set => title.Text = value; }


        public static readonly BindableProperty MyBackgroundColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(MyFrame), Color.LightPink);

        public Color MyBackgroundColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(MyBackgroundColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(MyBackgroundColorProperty, value);
        }


        public MyFrameXAML()
        {

            BindingContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
}
```

### Consume the new view

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="local:MyFrameXAML">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="MyBackgroundColor" Value="LimeGreen" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Style does apply!"
           FontSize="Title"
           TextColor="Black"/>
    <local:MyView>
        <local:MyView.Views>
            <local:MyFrameXAML Style="{StaticResource Style}"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               Title="Number one" />
        </local:MyView.Views>
    </local:MyView>

</StackLayout>
```

---

### Update

Reusable code

```cs
public static BindableProperty Override(
    this BindableProperty bindableProperty,
    string propertyName = null,
    Type returnType = null,
    Type declaringType = null,
    object defaultValue = null,
    BindingMode defaultBindingMode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    BindableProperty.ValidateValueDelegate validateValue = null,
    BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate propertyChanged = null,
    BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangingDelegate propertyChanging = null,
    BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate coerceValue = null,
    BindableProperty.CreateDefaultValueDelegate defaultValueCreator = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        propertyName = bindableProperty.PropertyName;
    if (returnType == null)
        returnType = bindableProperty.ReturnType;
    if (declaringType == null)
        declaringType = bindableProperty.DeclaringType;
    if (defaultValue == null)
        defaultValue = bindableProperty.DefaultValue;

    if (propertyChanged == null)
        propertyChanged = (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var property = bindableProperty.DeclaringType.GetProperty(bindableProperty.PropertyName);
            property.SetValue(bindable, newValue);
        };

    return BindableProperty.Create(propertyName, returnType, declaringType, defaultValue, defaultBindingMode,
        validateValue, propertyChanged, propertyChanging, coerceValue, defaultValueCreator);
}
```

```
public class MyFrame : Frame
{
    // override existing BindableProperty
    public static new readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorProperty = VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty.Override();

    private readonly Label _title;
    public string Title { set => _title.Text = value; }

    public MyFrame()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.LightPink;

        _title = new Label
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 16,
        };

         Content = _title;
    }
}
```